# How to combine a navlistPanel with sidebartLayout in a shiny web app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to combine a *navlistPanel* with *sidebartLayout* in a shiny web app. The idea is for the app to look like this:

[image]

But, when running the app, it´s not taking in the data and objects created in the *server.R*, nor the graph nor the table are shown in the app. Also, both the *conditionalPanel* and the *actionButton* does not work.

I have run the code without putting the sidebarLayout into the navlistePanel (only running the code with sidebarLayout) and it works perfectly. The problem comes when running the *sidebarLayout* inside the *navlistPanel*.

¿Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the code (I use it separated into 3 scripts: global, ui, and server).

```
# global.R <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

data <- airquality
meses <- unique(airquality$Month)
variables <- colnames(airquality)[-c(5,6)]
#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
shinyUI(

  fluidPage(

    navlistPanel("Panel de navegación",

                 tabPanel("General",

                          sidebarLayout(
                            
                            sidebarPanel(
                              
                              selectInput(inputId = "mes", label = "Selecciona un mes", choices = meses),
                              selectInput(inputId = "var", label = "Selecciona la variable Y", choices = variables),
                              checkboxInput(inputId = "cambiarTitulo", label = "Escribe un título", value = F),
                              conditionalPanel(condition = "input.cambiarTitulo == true",
                                               textInput(inputId = "titulo", label = "Escribe un título para la agráfica",
                                                         placeholder = "Tu título va aquí")),
                              actionButton(inputId = "boton", label = "Refrescar")
                            ),
                            
                            mainPanel(
                              
                              tabsetPanel(
                                
                                tabPanel(title = "Gráfica", plotOutput("grafica")),
                                tabPanel(title = "Datos", dataTableOutput("tabla"))
                              )
                            )
                          )
                 ),

                 tabPanel("Gráfica", plotOutput("grafica")),
                 tabPanel("Datos", DTOutput("tabla"))
    )
  )
)
#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    datosFiltrados <- reactive({
        datosNuevos <- data %>% filter(Month == input$mes)
        return(datosNuevos)
    })
    
    output$tabla <- renderDT(
        datatable(datosFiltrados(),
                  options = list(pageLenth = 10,
                                 lengthMenu = c(10,20)))
    )
    
    grafica <- eventReactive(input$boton, {
        
        if (input$cambiarTitulo == T) {
            ggplot(datosFiltrados()) +
                geom_point(aes_string(x = "Day", y = input$var)) +
                ggtitle(input$titulo)
        } else {
            ggplot(datosFiltrados()) +
                geom_point(aes_string(x = "Day", y = input$var))
        }
        
    })
    
    output$grafica <- renderPlot(grafica())
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicated IDs in UI `grafica` and `tabla`. ID duplication is not allowed in shiny.

If you need to have 2 components render the same thing in shiny, you still need to have unique IDs to each and watch closely how I make the duplications in the server.

```r
# global.R <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

data <- airquality
meses <- unique(airquality$Month)
variables <- colnames(airquality)[-c(5,6)]
#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ui <- fluidPage(
    navlistPanel("Panel de navegación",
                 
                 tabPanel("General",
                          
                          sidebarLayout(
                              
                              sidebarPanel(
                                  
                                  selectInput(inputId = "mes", label = "Selecciona un mes", choices = meses),
                                  selectInput(inputId = "var", label = "Selecciona la variable Y", choices = variables),
                                  checkboxInput(inputId = "cambiarTitulo", label = "Escribe un título", value = F),
                                  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.cambiarTitulo === true",
                                                   textInput(inputId = "titulo", label = "Escribe un título para la agráfica",
                                                             placeholder = "Tu título va aquí")),
                                  actionButton(inputId = "boton", label = "Refrescar")
                              ),
                              
                              mainPanel(
                                  
                                  tabsetPanel(
                                      
                                      tabPanel(title = "Gráfica", plotOutput("grafica")),
                                      tabPanel(title = "Datos", dataTableOutput("tabla"))
                                  )
                              )
                          )
                 ),
                 
                 tabPanel("Gráfica", plotOutput("grafica2")),
                 tabPanel("Datos", DTOutput("tabla2"))
    )
)
#<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    datosFiltrados <- reactive({
        datosNuevos <- data %>% filter(Month == input$mes)
        return(datosNuevos)
    })
    
    output$tabla <- output$tabla2 <- renderDT(
        datatable(datosFiltrados(),
                  options = list(pageLenth = 10,
                                 lengthMenu = c(10,20)))
    )
    
    grafica <- eventReactive(input$boton, {
        
        if (input$cambiarTitulo == T) {
            ggplot(datosFiltrados()) +
                geom_point(aes_string(x = "Day", y = input$var)) +
                ggtitle(input$titulo)
        } else {
            ggplot(datosFiltrados()) +
                geom_point(aes_string(x = "Day", y = input$var))
        }
        
    })
    
    output$grafica <- output$grafica2 <- renderPlot(grafica())
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for answering and for the solution. (I tried to vote your answer but I can´t because I'm below level 15. When this changes, I'll come back to vote).